# Matplotlib - Show axis break // in graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, break

I am trying to recreate the look of the following plot:

[image]

The breaking of the axis itself is quite straightforward as described here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html

But I have no idea how to include the // break in the graph itself. Any ideas?

Here is how it currently looks with my data.

[image: Here]

Answer (score 4):

The package [brokenaxes](https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes) is perfect for breaks in the axes as you are aware but it does not seem there is functionality for this in a published package. I have however figured out how to achieve what you are looking for.

First install the package from your environment directory in terminal:

```
>>> pip install brokenaxes
```

or

```
>>> conda install -c conda-forge brokenaxes
```

Solution:

```
from brokenaxes import brokenaxes
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_min    = 0
x_break  = 3
gap      = .1
x_max    = 6

def f(x):
    return np.cos(x)


fig  = plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
brax = brokenaxes(xlims=((x_min, x_break), (x_break+gap, x_max)), hspace=gap)
xs   = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 150)

brax.plot(xs, f(xs))
brax.annotate(u'—', (x_break-0.001, f(x_break)), rotation=45, size=25, ha='center', va='center', c='C0')
brax.annotate(u'—', (x_break+gap, f(x_break)), rotation=45, size=25, ha='center', va='center', c='C0')

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you are plotting from a an existing array, the function f could retrieve these values indexing from the array.

Comment: Yes, I saw this as well and it works great but I still see no option to include the break in the graph itself and not only in the axis (like in the example plot in my original post). Or am I just blind?

Comment: I apologise - I had misread your question at first. I deleted the initial response and (over the last 2 hours) figured out how to achieve what you are looking for. I hope this helps! Perhaps this functionality could be useful @ben.dichter?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! I can get it to work with your example but it is definitely pretty cumbersome with my data and with several stacked graphs. Was hoping there would be more straightforward solution to this but I'll have to make it work like his then.

Answer (score 1):

Use the example link https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html,
to achieve your target:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(19680801)

# creat data points
x = np.arange(20)+1
pts = x/x

# If we were to simply plot pts, we'd lose most of the interesting
# details due to the outliers. So let's 'break' or 'cut-out' the y-axis
# into two portions - use the top (ax1) for the outliers, and the bottom
# (ax2) for the details of the majority of our data
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.05)  # adjust space between axes

# plot the same data on both axes
ax1.plot(x, pts)
ax2.plot(x, pts)

# zoom-in / limit the view to different portions of the data
ax1.set_xlim(0, 10)  # left part plot
ax2.set_xlim(11, 19)  # right part plot

# hide the spines between ax and ax2
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
#ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
#ax1.tick_params(labeltop=False)  # don't put tick labels at the top
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()

# Now, let's turn towards the cut-out slanted lines.
# We create line objects in axes coordinates, in which (0,0), (0,1),
# (1,0), and (1,1) are the four corners of the axes.
# The slanted lines themselves are markers at those locations, such that the
# lines keep their angle and position, independent of the axes size or scale
# Finally, we need to disable clipping.

d = .9  # proportion of vertical to horizontal extent of the slanted line
kwargs = dict(marker=[(-1, -d), (1, d)], markersize=12,
              linestyle="none", color='k', mec='k', mew=1, clip_on=False)
ax1.plot([1, 1], [0, 1], transform=ax1.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax2.plot([0, 0], [0, 1], transform=ax2.transAxes, **kwargs)

# add slanted line on the graph
ax1.plot([1], [0.5], transform=ax1.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax2.plot([0], [0.5], transform=ax2.transAxes, **kwargs) 
#fig.savefig('_')

plt.show()
```

the result like
[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that the range of the different axes needs to be the same or the scaling will be off. The brokenaxes package above solves this but introduces other complications. So, seems there isn't really a good way to do this...

Comment: OK. Hope you solve the other complications soon.